# Nativescript NativeAPI can't find NSURL, NSURLRequest, NSObject

Tags: cocoapods, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to Implement Native API in Nativescript Angular to add WebSocket support using StompClient.

Already added template declaration using
`npm i tns-platform-declarations --save-dev` and configured exactly as per the documentation.

but when I run the project it can't find
`Cannot find name 'NSURLRequest'` , `NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString(url))`, `Cannot find name 'NSObject'`

However, in vs code it is able to find using autocomplete.

Any good suggestions pls?

Comment: Although it should be able to detect once you added the platform declarations, but can you try to add at the top of your file/component: ```declare var android: any;```

Comment: and ```declare var ios: any;``` then see if that works.

Comment: @Raven did already but not working. Don't know what is wrong with it